# Ruby - array issue - line from file

Tags: arrays, ruby, file-io

I am trying to write a simple ruby script to parse some device config.
I am reading the config from a txt file line by line and if I come across a match I want to read the lines into an `array` and paste that `array` to an output file.

```
if $match == 1 

 my_array.insert($j,/#{line}/)

 $j += 1


somefile_log.puts ("DEBUG : Array at #{$j} is #{my_array[$j]}")
```

I am messing up the index aspect. 
`**J**` increments but the `array` value stays the same as the first line it reads. Thoughts ?

Comment: Your code doesn't even run.

Comment: Using global variables like `$j` and `$match` is a very bad habit to get into. These are not like PHP where `$x` is local to the function, these are program wide, at the root level, meaning all instances of `$j` are identical.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete mess. In ruby we would do it in the following way:

```
match = /TEST/ # no need for global variables

result = File.readlines('/foo/bar/file.name').select do |line|
  line =~ match
end

result.each_with_index do |line, idx|
  somefile_log.puts "DEBUG : Array at #{idx} is #{line}"
end
```

Or, even better,

```
File.readlines.grep(match)
```

as suggested in comments by Jörg W. Mittag